# get server file data whenever the file updated using javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, logfile

I want to get whole data from a specific file (which has log data from some logic) and show on the web using javascript whenever the file updated.

I have no idea to do this.

had similar experience like this? if so please teach me whether it was good or not.

Comment: How about take a look at websocket? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is to let server inform the client when the server's file updated, right?

AFAIK, there're several way to do so.

I list two of the ways which are famous way as I know:

1. [WebSocket](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)
2. long polling - [ajax example](https://gist.github.com/jhbsk/4353139)

Both of two have much information you would need.